# C# BackgroundWorker_DoWork only does some of the work

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker

This one has me stumped.  I have a simple utility I made to help with an enterprise installation of software.  One component backs up AppData files the user currently has on their machine and saves them to a folder on the desktop:

```
private void backupButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundBackup.RunWorkerAsync();
}


private void backgroundBackup_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}

private static void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
{
    ...
}

// I removed the message boxes from DoWork, and added a RunWorkerCompleted event, 
// but neither the confirmation nor the error messgae box from RunWorkerCompleted are shown.

private void backgroundBackup_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

This works, but does not produce the expected results.  I put this operation on a background thread because the total file size each user is backing up may approach a gb or two.  Each time this is run, some, but not all of the files and folders from the target are copied to the destination, and the folders that are copied varies each time.  Sometimes only a handful of files and folders are copied, sometimes almost all everything is copied, but never the entire target.  If this operation is placed in a simple console app, it works every time.  Is there anything I need to understand about the BackgroundWorker class that is causing it to not do all the work in the DoWork method?

Edit:

I think I may be over complicating the issue with the BackgroundWorker class.  I spoke to a coworker, and they suggested a simple way of creating a new thread to handle a potentially lengthy process:

```
    private void backupButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread backupThread = new Thread(backupThreadJob);
        backupThread.Start();      
    }

    private void backupThreadJob()
    {
        try
        {
            //copy files and stuff
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This gets the job done for me; I was unsuccessful in my attempts to use BackgroundWorker and was never able to figure out why only some files were being copied.  Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: I would guess that some exceptions are being raised but your message boxes do not show because you're calling from a background thread and not the main UI thread.  You probably should be invoking those methods on the UI thread.

Comment: I'd expect that you have an exception and that the message box isn't shown because it's not the UI thread. Try to log the exception instead and in general never consume all exceptions. It makes debugging a nightmare as you have probably realised by now

Comment: Have you ever seen the MessageBox that you have in your catch block?  Try throwing a hard-coded exception in your background thread to see if the messagebox is displayed.  My guess is that your process is throwing errors.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding properly how RunWorkerCompleted is called, as neither the error or confirmation message boxes in my revised code are shown when DoWork is called.  The MSDN example for the BackgroundWorker class leads me to believe that once DoWork is complete, RunWorkerCompleted automatically is called.

Comment: Please show how your BackgroundWork is being created / attached.

Comment: It is still being called in a worker thread... not the UI thread.  You need to [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.invoke.aspx) it.  `this.Invoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show(yourMessage)));`

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, I think I was over complicating things and made some edits as described above.

Comment: Without the detail of the code that actually isn't completing, readers are going to stabbing in the dark.

Comment: @matt.f.c, remember, you *must not* do UI work on any other thread than the main thread. This is still the case (you call `MessageBox.Show` on a separate thread) with your modified code.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a complete answer. But I could imagine that the following has something to do with the problem:

Remember that `BackgroundWorker` executes your `DoWork` method on another, non-UI thread, so it's not a good idea to call `MessageBox.Show` there. You should only do UI stuff if you're running on the UI ("foreground") thread:

> *You must be careful not to manipulate any user-interface objects in your DoWork event handler. Instead, communicate to the user interface through the ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events.*
>    — [MSDN reference page for the `BackgroundWorker` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

I could imagine that if an exception occurs somewhere in your method, and you want to show a message box in the `catch` block, this call triggers yet another exception, which doesn't get handled... and thus your method aborts prematurely.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I removed the message boxes from DoWork, and added a RunWorkerCompleted event, but neither the confirmation nor the error messgae box from RunWorkerCompleted are shown.

Comment: From the first example code in the MSDN reference sheet you linked to, am I wrong in my assumption that RunWorkerCompleted is automatically called upon completion of DoWork?

Comment: @matt.f.c Are you sure you are wiring up the event handler?   bw.RunWorkerCompleted += BwOnRunWorkerCompleted;

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example showing you can call message boxes from the back ground threads.  MessageBox.Show is a static method call and can be called from the back ground thread.  You should never attempt to access anything on your UI layer (including bound backing objects - think WPF here).

Here is an example of where this would be used for message boxes.

I want to copy 10 files and I start the copy process in the background.  An error occurs (file exists, etc) and you want to prompt the user to overwrite - you could show a message box requesting confirmation from the user.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += BwOnRunWorkerCompleted;
    bw.DoWork += BwOnDoWork;
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void BwOnDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs doWorkEventArgs)
{
    MessageBox.Show("This is a message from a background thread");
}

private void BwOnRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs runWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Your done");
}
```